# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'..while editing CSV

Tags: python, csv, xlwings

Consider the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw 
directory("C:\\Users\Ritesh\PycharmProjects\BS\Test1.csv") 
wb = xw.Book(directory) 
sht = wb.sheets['Test1'] 
count = 1 
for row in range(2, 200):
    A = 'A%s' % row
    B = 'B%s' % row
    C = 'C%s' % row
    D = 'D%s' % row
    rays = sht.range(A).value
    line = rays.strip().strip(" ")
    code = line.split(" ")[0]
    sht.range('D1').value = 'Code'
    sht.range(D).value = code
```

Please help me to solve this, as it is showing an error like:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Comment: Hi there. You may want to debug the question yourself first. Checkout `ipdb`. In this case, either `rays` or `rays.strip()` is None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line here

```
directory("C:\\Users\Ritesh\PycharmProjects\BS\Test1.csv")
```

perhaps looks like a valid Python syntax, but it shouldn't be valid because that is a function call `directory(x)` with `x` as a parameter. It wasn't valid in Python2 & it's not valid in Python3 because there's no function `directory` declared before that line. So by that logic your error would not have been `AttributeError` since the error occured before the line `wb = xw.Book(directory)` is reached. Please edit and include the complete exception error.

Second, I just did a quick search in xlwings documentation and I couldn't find any function `directory` in it. Was `directory` some function you didn't include in code you posted here? Please double check if it's a cut+paste problem of accidentally left out or explain how you got that directory function.

ps: your path looks wrong too, iirc in windows the path would be `C:\` with a single backslash instead of double, but that might still works, my recollection of windows is quite fuzzy.